# What type of code is this

Tags: encryption

I found this code and had trouble decoding it,
4 4   6 5   6 3   7 2   7 9   7 0   7 4   6 9   6 f   6 e   2 0   3 3   2 f   3 3   2 0   4 3   6 f   6 d   7 0   6 c   6 5   7 4   6 5   6 4   2 e   0 d   0 a   4 4   6 f   7 7   6 e   6 c   6 f   6 1   6 4   6 9   6 e   6 7   2 0   6 6   6 9   6 c   6 5   7 3   2 0   7 4   6 f   2 0   7 4   6 5   6 d   7 0   6 f   7 2   6 1   7 2   7 9   2 0   6 6   6 f   6 c   6 4   6 5   7 2   3 a   0 d   0 a   6 8   7 4   7 4   7 0   7 3   3 a   2 f   2 f   7 7   7 7   7 7   2 e   6 4   7 2   6 f   7 0   6 2   6 f   7 8   2 e   6 3   6 f   6 d   2 f   7 3   6 8   2 f   7 7   7 0   6 e   3 1   7 a   6 1   7 9   6 3   6 9   3 2   3 8   6 9   6 d   6 7   3 6   2 f   4 1   4 1   4 2   6 d   5 0   5 f   5 0   4 1   7 9   5 8   6 d   7 0   7 3   6 d   4 e   5 8   4 a   4 1   6 8   6 8   7 6   4 9   4 e   3 9   6 1   3 f   6 4   6 c   3 d   3 0﻿

Comment: I believe it is an obscure code known as 'ASCII', with each two letters/numbers combining to form a single hex value 0x00 - 0xff

Comment: Vulcans call it _"interspaced lowercase big-endian hexadecimal-encoded ASCII with Crimosoft line endings"_. Don't ever get them started on the logic of different line endings...

Answer (score 1):

It's plain text, encoded in either ISO 8859-1 or Unicode (for these character ranges, it doesn't matter):

```
Decryption 3/3 Completed.
Downloading files to temporary folder:
https://www.dropbox.com/sh/wpn1zayci28img6/AABmP_PAyXmpsmNXJAhhvIN9a?dl=0
```

I found this text by grouping the characters in groups of 2, copy/pasting into a hex editor, then copying the resultant text back in to Notepad.

Comment: Thanks, but thats a bit odd as i tried ISO 8859, and all the variations.

Comment: @Ravaen It required conversion from hex back to binary data. That might have been why it confused you. Having a hex editor around is always useful for situations like this.